# Chef "file" resource with huge content

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am using the file resource and specifying the file contents to the content attribute. However, the content is huge and I cannot declare the content directly within the file attribute.

```
file "/var/django/.ssh/id_rsa" do
  content "huge content"
  owner "django"
  group "django"
  mode 00600
end
```

Please suggest if there is a better way to declare the content(when content is huge).

Comment: Declaring `content` on a file resource is generally only appropriate when the content is being dynamically generated in your cookbook somewhere.  If it is static, you should be using `cookbook_file` and storing the file the way @coderanger suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, you mentioned you don't want a separate file, the correct way to create a private SSH key would be to use encrypted data bags.  The easiest way to manage encrypted data bags is through chef vault.  You can read more about how to get setup with Chef vault here: http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2013/09/10/managing-secrets-with-chef-vault/.

```
vault_ssh = ChefVault::Item.load("secrets", "vaultuser-ssh-private")

directory "/home/vaultuser/.ssh" do
  owner "vaultuser"
  group "vaultuser"
  mode 0700
end

file "/home/vaultuser/.ssh/id_rsa" do
  content vault_ssh["vaultuser-ssh-private"]
  owner "vaultuser"
  group "vaultuser"
  mode 0600
end
```

If you wanted to skip the data bag you could just set the value of the vault_ssh["vaultuser-ssh-private"] attribute to the key, or have it set to a node attribute in your role/cookbook.

Answer (score 1):

Put the content in a file under `files/` in the cookbook and use a `cookbook_file` resource.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to use cookbook_file because that way I will need to include a separate file. I want everything to be part of the string only.

Comment: You can't ask for a better way and then say you want to do it exactly the way you asked to not do.

Answer (score 0):

Using a cookbook_file resource as coderanger described is probably the more correct way of doing this.

But if you really want to do it without a separate file, you can use a heredoc with the file resource.

```
file '/tmp/somefile' do
  content <<-EOF.gsub(/^\s+/, '')
    some line here
    some other line here
    more lines
    EOF
end
```